# Order by ordinal column number that is out of range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

It's possible to sort MySQL results by ordinal column number in the result set, like this:

```
select id, firstname, lastname from customer order by 3,2
```

(which sorts by `lastname` and then `firstname`)

However, if you specify a column number that does not exist, such as 4 in my example, you get an error:  *Unknown column '4' in 'order clause'*

I have some legacy user-interface code where the number of columns coming back from various queries is not known in advance. Due to the structure of this code, to add a sort facility, it would help me to be able to specify a non-existent column number without getting an error. (The sort order doesn't matter if the number is outside the actual column range.)

Is there a way to do this somehow at the SQL level? Perhaps something like:

```
order by min(3, number_of_columns_in_result_set)
```

Comment: You should use the names rather than an ordinal number.

Comment: Noway. Even when you use a number in ORDER BY it is used as a literal - hence you cannot use an expression. And this value parsing is performed before the query execution, so the value which you want to refer to not exists when the query text is parsed.

Comment: I can see that maybe it can be done using a prepared statement. What's the next step after finding out the column exists or not?

Comment: I don't understand why someone says "you SHOULD do this" and gets all the points and my question, based on dealing with real legacy code (did you guys never have to get something done by Friday?) gets downvote hate.  If I had written the identical question but phrased it "I am  just curious is it possible" you would probably have been fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. But you could wrap it in a prepared statement and deal with that sub-result set (thank you FaNo_FN).